# Http java file download problem

Tags: java, http, url, download, httpclient

Trying to download file with apache httpclient library and have a problem with resulting file being smaller than the original (approximately 32-32kb, when normal file size is 92-93) and cannot be opened normally in pdf viewer. 
Can someone explain me why this can be happening ? (Using firefox to download  this file can sometimes lead to file being downloaded fully and sometimes being downloaded partly)

Here is code I was using to download file via URL

```
    URL url = new URL("pathtofile");
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://result1.pdf");

    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead; 
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {        
        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    is.close();
```

P.S. Was trying to download this file using HttpClient apache library, same result.

UPDATED: Monitoring traffic with network tool I found the difference between receiving file via Firefox and application.

With Firefox first HttpPayloadLine was :

`HTTPPayloadLine: 83 Td
/F2 5.80476 Tf
(A:\040Asinis\04017.12.10\04008:32\040laboratorij) Tj
100 Tz
1 1 1 rg
/F1 5.80476 Tf
0 0 0 rg
104.4856 0 Td
<0145> Tj
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
3.62799 0.72565 Td
/F2 5.80476 Tf
(\040) Tj
1 1 1 rg
0.83137 0.81569 0.78431 RG
ET
51`

With application first HttpPayload was

`HTTPPayloadLine: CWgC,ú&ÿ3@Î"Ý¯V¨®~×>×)\ªleÚl`µï½ci
¤Ãðð'È/CÈAø¯ª   Í`übA«1Ãÿ   Åç«VÉ¬ZòYóóy7»ÇH.o²e<qZna3l±°¥þ6ñþ[2YÚ1ì³Eë-ÓÊÏ$y:tÎà![ËÅS¤¿É¡¢è,þ|ºs¨)@¢Qâ¯ÝF~}oµÒ>¦ OAxz³äÒ.ß9
æÃZ¤ùÒ¨*«øUÎ®+4×`

This measurements was taken via Microsoft Network Monitor

**LAST UPDATE** It was a server problem after all, after they fixed that files are downloaded successful

Comment: If you read the URL connection input stream you will read "everything" that comes from server. If "pathtofile" is a http request the servers output will include some header information that cannot be processed by the pdf viewer. What is the contents of the file that is downloaded so far ? It is starting with "%PDF" ?

Comment: Curious: Is there a Content-Encoding header on the HTTP response?

Comment: No Content-Encoding header in response

Comment: Regarding that firefox sometimes downloads fine and sometimes not i would investigate the server further, if you have access to the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to

```
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
 byte[] tmp = ArrayUtils.subarray(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 fos.write(tmp);
}
```

you mite get 0 bytes back but that does not mean its finished.Also write only bytes that you received not buffer.

Comment: The `java.io.OutputStream` already provides a `write(byte b[], int off, int len)` method.

Comment: yip i know just tried to make more clear what i am doing.     fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I spotted is that you check whether `is.read(buffer) > 0`, which is wrong, as it may (in theory, at least) return 0 even if it's not reached the end of file. `InputStream.read()` will return `-1` when EOF is reached, so make that comparison `>= 0`.

EDIT:
The second thing that I spotted (a little late, as it's already been noticed in other answers) is that you're writing the whole buffer to the output stream no matter how much of it was actually affected by the latest read operation. Try something like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead;
while ( (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0 ) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: @artjomka: Have you also modified your code like in my latest edit or in Pintac's answer ?

Comment: I modified it like in you latest edit (And update main post with changes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reading the error stream can give you some information:

```
connection.getErrorStream();
```

Comment: cant find getErrorStream method for URLConnection class

Comment: Right, it's a method of HttpURLConnection. If your connection is HTTP, do:
`((HttpURLConnection)connection).getErrorStream();`

Comment: This method returns null in my case

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)` instead?