# Using HTTPConnection to one site to download binary files makes some errors

Tags: java, httpconnection

To make my life easier at work, I'm making a Java program to download some modules off the server (Sometimes they get deleted off of my local machine and it takes 15 minutes to build them all).
Following is my code for downloading the files:

Note that all files are less than a megabyte big.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.url.com/ModuleName.swf");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int n = -1;

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("dlFile.swf"));

    while ((n = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        output.flush();
    }
    output.close();
```

If I use a hex editor to compare the file downloaded via Java andvia Firefox, it's almost the same at first. But later on there's so many errors.

Now, the strange thing is this: If I use Firefox to download the file and upload that file to dropbox, the file will be downloaded correctly with my application.

Any idea what could possibly cause this?

Comment: This SO question might help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198946/http-java-file-download-problem

Comment: Just a question: are you using Java 7?